# Is it possible to communicate without server on android (peer to peer)?

Tags: android, p2p

I am developing an app and curious about p2p communication.
Without server nor IP, can my device connect to another device with only a phone number?

My plan is to communicate two devices with phone numbers over 3G network.
(No c2dm)
Like  a messaging app, I want to send and receive the data such as location information with my friend.

First of all, the app should be installed on both devices. Secondly, this app makes these devices communicate with each other. So whenever I want to know my friend's location, I can request his or her location through this app. When my friend replies to this request, the app will send me its location info.

If the device knows only a phone number of my friend, can this device communicate with my friend's device?

Comment: It can if you have ip information of the phone number on a server. You can first contact that server to get your friends ip using the phone number

Comment: I want to communication without server :(

Comment: are malware author ?

Answer (score 0):

I believed you will not be able to do that since you want to communicate over the 3G network. Assuming you want to communicate over the internet. You should use some standard protocol such as SMTP for email. There must also be a way for one phone to advertise itself or to search for the targeted phone. Usually this is done via a server which stores a mapping of phone no to ip or mac address of the device.

If you want to do direct communication perhaps Bluetooth will be a better option.

Hope e expert here can shed more light.

Update : Can the downvote be explained ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on wifi network ...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html